# Display table is exceeding parent height in every browser but Chrome

Tags: css

I'm trying to stack 2 divs of variable height one on top of the other. Both divs combined should not exceed the container height. The 2nd div should allow scrolling if it gets too big.

I've done some research on how to make a div take the remaining height and it pointed me towards display: table-row. I can't use absolute positioning because I don't know what the height of the 1st div will be as it is also variable.

The problem appears to be that the table will always expand vertically with the content unless I use a fixed height on one of the divs.

Here's a JSBin of the problem: http://jsbin.com/heyam/3/edit?html,css,output

It works fine in Chrome but doesn't work in any other browser. I've read dozens of threads on SO with similar problems but none of the answers gave me a working solution. My browser support includes the latest versions of FF, Chrome, Safari and IE9+.

Is there a CSS-only solution to this problem or am I stuck using JS on this one?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Becuase i'm in very this situation and still have no solution that do not use flexbox

Answer (score 1):

```
.slideout {
    display: table;
    float:right;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Tested this in Firefox and the yellow div is not scrollable even though it should be.

Comment: `.scrollInner {  height: 100%;  overflow-y: scroll;}`

Comment: I understand very well how overflow works... Your answer simply doesn't solve the problem. The only things you've changed were float right instead of absolute position and overflow-y scroll instead overflow auto.